# Firestore query orderBy not working?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

FutureBuilder with a Firestore query on a field of Type timestamp comes back with no data in snapshot.  However, the same query without the orderBy works just fine.
What am  I missing ? Thanks for the help.

```
// Working code
future: Firestore.instance.collection('messages').where('toid',isEqualTo: _emailID).getDocuments(),
builder: (context, snapshot) ...

// Not Working - returns to if(!snapshot.hasData)
future: Firestore.instance.collection('messages').where('toid',isEqualTo: _emailID).orderBy('_timeStampUTC', descending: true).getDocuments(),
builder: (context, snapshot) ...
```

[image]

Comment: can your share some code using which you get the solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are missing a `'` here `'_timeStampUTC`, so it should be:

```
 orderBy('_timeStampUTC', descending: true)
```

**EDIT:**

Also, you need to be sure to create an index for `toid` and other for `_timeStampUTC`, this is done when you try to order by a property that is not in you the where of the query.

Comment: Sorry about that. That was a typo on my part I was typing by memory.  I have corrected the question.  Thanks.

Comment: Mmm ok, then, have you tried to create [an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview) for `_timeStampUTC`?

Comment: just tried the index on the '_timeStampUTC' field - no luck.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that good with Dart, and was looking at [their docs](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/lib/src/query.dart#L147), and everything looks right... I see you are not [the only one with this problem](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15928), but the way they resolved it was by creating an index

Comment: I'm trying your idea again. After some digging I have found you have to put the index on the where field and the orderBy field

Comment: You were correct about the index.  However, with to issues -1.  the index MUST be created on whatever fields you are querying - 2. indexes MUST be in the order of your query.  I had to create the 'toid' index first then the '_timeStampUTC' second...then it worked.  Can you  update your answer with these points and I will mark as correct.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AhabLives I am facing exactly same issue, but I am using StreamBuilder. Can you guide how to set up index? I set up CompositeIndex

See image: https://imgur.com/iTEY6eX

When I add new document, stream builder does not show in ListView where as If I remove orderby part it show live updates/ add / deleted

Comment: @Wikki did you solved it? I am also getting the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are still facing issue and don't know how to add indexes

Click on Add Index from **Firebase console:** `Cloud Firestore indexes` section:
You need to add collection id, fields and query scope and create Index. It will take some times to build index.

[image]

After adding index on fields you will get below with status enabled
[image]

Comment: It works for me, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Use  `@ServerTimestamp` annotation for `_timeStampUTC`  and try to to orderBy query

> To make Firestore automatically generate Timestamp values when we
>   upload data to the database, we must use the annotation
>   @ServerTimestamp and set the value to null.

Answer (score 0):

yep, it's just missing an index.  if you're using firestore.indexes.json then add this:

```
{
  "collectionId": "messages",
  "fields": [
    { "fieldPath": "toid", "mode": "ASCENDING" },
    { "fieldPath": "_timeStampUTC", "mode": "DESCENDING" }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write your query:-

```dart
Firestore.instance.collection('messages').where('toid',isEqualTo: _emailID).orderBy('_timeStampUTC', descending: true).getDocuments()
```

after this, in your log, a link will be generated. it will soething like this https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project............
follow that link to create index for your query after creating the index reload your app and now you will be able to fetch all your collections. :)