# Firestore end before documents not working properly

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the below query to get documents before given documents snapshot. when I use descending: false
I get initial 5 documents but I want immediate 5 documents before the given documents. When I use descending: true  I get an empty list. Please help me. What I am doing wrong here.

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getConversationBefore(String currentUserID,String clientID,DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot)
      {
           return Firestore.instance
            .collection(FIREBASE_COLLECTION_MESSAGES)
            .document(currentUserID)
            .collection(clientID)
            .orderBy(TIMESTAMP_FIELD, descending: false)
            .endBeforeDocument(documentSnapshot)
            .limit(5)
            .snapshots();
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
Also make sure you have initialized an index on the field you are trying to order by, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434167/firestore-query-orderby-not-working)!

```
return Firestore.instance
            .collection(FIREBASE_COLLECTION_MESSAGES)
            .document(currentUserID)
            .collection(clientID)
            .orderBy('TIMESTAMP_FIELD', descending: true)
            .endBeforeDocument(documentSnapshot)
            .limit(5)
            .snapshots();
```

Comment: i made an edit, i am not sure what you mean "not accepting desc argument", unless i have missunderstood your stack, and its not firebase... otherwise the snippet is from the examples!

Comment: I am using firestore flutter plugin where order by is accepting a field and optional boolean value not a string

Comment: Take a look here, if it helps tell me to change my answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434167/firestore-query-orderby-not-working

Comment: I will try this