# flutterfire where and orderby not return data

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

i have implemented this code for retrieving the messages of this room.

```
final messagesProvider = StreamProvider((ref) {
  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
var room = ref.watch(roomIdProvider);
  print('room updated');
  print('room is '+room);
  final docRef = db
.collection("messages")

.where("chat_room_id",isEqualTo: room)
    // .orderBy('created_at')
    // .orderBy('created_at',descending: true)



;
print(docRef.orderBy("created_at").snapshots());

  return docRef.snapshots();
});
```

i want to sort the data and have tried these two lines separately but not worked for me

```
     .orderBy('created_at')
     .orderBy('created_at',descending: true)
```

where created at is a timestamp field.

Comment: Here, there are some examples about this ([order by not returning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434167/firestore-query-orderby-not-working) and [firestore order by](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15928)) and in all of them it is recommended to use the index. You can follow the [instructions here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15928#issuecomment-619352394) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I added a new collection called "school", there're two items added inside the document.

I used my code, and it works. Could you please remove ".where" and try it again?

```dart
  void getMessagesTest() async{
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _firestore.collection('school').orderBy('age',descending: true).get();
    final allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
    print(allData);
  }
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Updated 20220616:
[image]

Updated 20220618:
Yes, you could chain where and orderBy together. Please see my code below.
Reference link => [Using Where and Order by different fields in Firestore query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70148800/using-where-and-order-by-different-fields-in-firestore-query)

```dart
  void getMessagesTest() async{
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _firestore.collection('school').orderBy('age', descending: true).where('age', isGreaterThan: 17).get();
    final allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
    print(allData);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Frederic , what if i want to get students where there ages is equal to 18

Comment: Please use where to filter data. It should work for your application.

Comment: i do use it and get the error after chain it with orderBy

Comment: I've updated my comment, yes you could chain both orderBy  and where together.